# Javascript configure Server URL and store it

Tags: javascript, html, rest, service, configuration

I got the following setup:

A service running under a URL or IP or whatever installed inhouse on a server and a JavaScript/HTML app installed somewhere else which provides user interfaces for the service.

Now I do not want to hardcode the URL of the service in the UI-App. Is there any solution or best practise to make the URL configurable on installation or first startup?

Thanks and Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Save your Url in Browsers local Storage. On first Startup easily ask the user for the url.

```
// Store
localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
```

Comment: I already thought about this, but the problem is, that I would net to set this up per browser or user. What I search for is a global solution.